# HTTPServer Post parameters

Tags: java, httpserver

Am writing a service using the `HTTPServer` provided by `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` package. I need to send some sizable data as a byte stream to this service (say a million integers).

I have almost searched all the examples available, all point to sending a small `GET` request in the URL. 
I need to know how to send the data as a `POST` request. 
Also is there any limit on the data that can be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than persistent URL connection in the answer above, I would recommend using Apache HTTPClient libraries (if you are not using Spring for applet-servlet communication)

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

In this you can build a client and send a serialized object (for instance serialised to JSON string: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ) as POST request over HTTP to your server:

```
public HttpResponse sendStuff (args) {
    HttpPost post = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        post = new HttpPost(servletUrl);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(<nameString>, <valueString>));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However Spring saves you a lot of time and hassle so I would recommend to [check it out](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data for the POST request by writing bytes to the connections output stream as shown below

```
public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
{
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;    
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                 "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                         Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");    

        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response  
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect(); 
        }
    }
}
```

With POST, there is no limit on the amount of data that can be sent. You can find out the details about the limitations of GET here [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to send requests in direction of your `HTTPServer`, as a GET request instead of using post.

In your HTTP Client implementation you can set the HTTP Headers and also the request Method:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); //Or POST
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: No thats the exact opposite. I want data to be sen as POST, and also sizable data as said.